# Кластеризация готовой карты на основе яндекс - конструктора

Tags: yandex-maps-api

На вордпрес собираю простенький сайтик. Имеется карта сделанная в яндекс конструкторе.
Насчет вставки - вопросов нет.

Хотел бы реализовать кластеризацию меток. В интернете и в "песочнице яндекс" даны примеры. Но в этих примерах не понимаю куда вставлять код готовой карты. В примерах и в интернете подобного разбора нет.

В общем, буду благодарен любой информации.
Ибо в области программирования "0".

сам код карты:
 `<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/services/constructor/1.0/js/?um=constructor%3Ae20d09917a58ef01768d1d6909593ebe77e6d9d09f404de8face2c9cc8393749&amp;width=100%25&amp;height=450&amp;lang=ru_RU&amp;scroll=true"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

В код [Конструктора](https://yandex.ru/map-constructor/) кластеризацию никак не интегрировать. Эта возможность реализована только в [JS API Яндекс Карт](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/).

Пример импорта объектов, созданных в Конструкторе на карту JS API есть в песочнице Яндекс: https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/object_manager_geojson

Добавить в этот код кластеризацию можно, уточнив для менеджера объектов пару опций:

```
    objectManager = new ymaps.ObjectManager({
        clusterize: true,
        gridSize: 64
    });
```

Пример кластеризации объектов ObjectManager также есть в песочнице:
https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/object_manager/